# Mongodb integration testing. Test data is not created

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, embed

I am trying to test my mongodb dao using embedded mongodb- but the test data is not being created.

By contrast, if I use the same way to creating objects in real db then it works OK.

This is my config:

```java
public class UnmappableDataDAOTest
{
    private static final String LOCALHOST = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "itest";
    private static final int MONGO_TEST_PORT = 27028;
    private static final String CONTRACT_COLLECTION = "ContractAnswers";

    private UnmappableDataDAO dao;

    private static MongodProcess mongoProcess;
    private static Mongo mongo;

    private MongoTemplate template;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void initializeDB() throws IOException
    {
        RuntimeConfig config = new RuntimeConfig();
        config.setExecutableNaming(new UserTempNaming());

        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getInstance(config);

        MongodExecutable mongoExecutable = starter.prepare(new MongodConfig(Version.V2_2_0, MONGO_TEST_PORT, false));
        mongoProcess = mongoExecutable.start();

        mongo = new Mongo(LOCALHOST, MONGO_TEST_PORT);
        mongo.getDB(DB_NAME);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void shutdownDB() throws InterruptedException {
        mongo.close();
        mongoProcess.stop();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        dao = new UnmappableDataDAO();
        template = new MongoTemplate(mongo, DB_NAME);
        dao.setMongoOperations(template);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        template.dropCollection(ContractAnswers.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate()
    {
        // Setup Test Data
        List<ContractAnswers> contractAnswersList = new ArrayList<>();

        ContractAnswers first = new ContractAnswers();
        first.setContractId(1L);
        first.setTemplateName("firstTemplate");
        first.setId("1");
        contractAnswersList.add(first);

        ContractAnswers second = new ContractAnswers();
        second.setContractId(2L);
        second.setTemplateName("secondTemplate");
        second.setId("2");
        contractAnswersList.add(second);

        for (ContractAnswers contractAnswers : contractAnswersList)
        {
            template.save(contractAnswers, CONTRACT_COLLECTION);
        }

        ContractAnswers third = new ContractAnswers();
        third.setContractId(3L);
        third.setTemplateName("thirdTemplate");
        third.setId("3");
        dao.create(third);

        List<ContractAnswers> list = template.findAll(ContractAnswers.class);
     }
}
```

The result of findAll() method is null. That means, that data has not been created.

When I use this way of creation: `template.save(contractAnswers, CONTRACT_COLLECTION);`, test data *is* created, but I need the way with CONTRACT_COLLECTION as a parameter. All methods in my dao depend on it.

It is strange, but this is how my create method looks like and it works OK:

```
public void createOrUpdate(ContractAnswers contractAnswers)
    {
        this.mongoOperations.save(contractAnswers, CONTRACT_COLLECTION);
    }
```

The same code works ok in real database, but not work in test.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sviatlana - can I ask you to clarify something please? You say that this code `template.save(contractAnswers, CONTRACT_COLLECTION)` _does_work - so what is it in your full code which is not working?

Comment: @Vince Bowdren this is my full code of this method

Comment: Hi Sviatlana - I've edited your question to make the wording a little clearer, but I still don't understand which code is working and which code is not working. In the main code block, it says `template.save(contractAnswers, CONTRACT_COLLECTION);` and you say that is _not_ working; but in the paragraph below you say that `template.save(contractAnswers, CONTRACT_COLLECTION);` _is_ working - and I can't tell the difference, they look exactly the same to me.

Comment: @Vince Bowdren  The same code works ok in real database, but not works in test. (edited a lil bit, thank you)